# jQuery Mobile Dynamic Content Insertion

Tags: jquery, dynamic, jquery-mobile, pagefunction

Ok, would someone help me figure out why the "test" li in the following code isn't visible? I inspected the live dom and the elements do seem to be getting processed:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
<html> 
<head> 

  <!-- Grab Google CDN's jQuery, with a protocol relative URL; fall back to local if necessary -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" />
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('<div data-role="content" class="content"><ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"><li><a href="#im?at=animals">test</a></li></ul></div>').appendTo("#home").page();
      $.mobile.changePage("#home", {transition: "none"});
  });
  </script>
</head> 

<body> 
<div id="home" data-role="page"> 
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The call to changePage doesn't work because you only have a single page which is visible/active by default. 
You can force the active page to update by triggering the create event.

```
$('<div data-role="content" class="content"><ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"><li><a href="#im?at=animals">test</a></li></ul></div>').appendTo("#home");
$.mobile.changePage("#home", {transition: "none"});  
$.mobile.activePage.trigger('create');
```

Answer (score 0):

The element below has `display` property set to `none` and it hides its siblings:

```
<div data-role="content" class="content ui-page ui-body-c ui-content" tabindex="0" role="main">
```

The CSS rule:

```
.ui-mobile [data-role="page"], .ui-mobile [data-role="dialog"], .ui-page {
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
position: absolute;
display: none;
border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of the correct jquery mobile method that triggers it to display? I thought that's what changePage would do with transition none.

Comment: I've just checked the `test`'s ancestors to see why `test` is invisible and found that one of them (at least) has `display: none`.